# error in online c compiler when using typedef __unaligned struct __attribute__((packed))

Tags: c

Hi need to understand the size difference of structure in c , hence doing a small experiment for learning

```
typedef __unaligned struct __attribute__((packed)){
int a;
int b;

}a_b;

printf("%d", sizeof(a_b));
```

but not able to compile this in any online c compiler , kindly suggest ,however this works in my keil ide with c99 standard and compiler 6.19 arm , need suggestion. Thanks.

for reference arm link:

```
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0742/h/compiler-source-code-compatibility/language-extension-compatibility--keywords
```

But if i try

```
struct {
int a;
int b;
}a_b;
```

it works.

Comment: You have tagged the question with the tag [`compiler-construction`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/compiler-construction/info), which has the following description at the top: "The tag compiler-construction should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. DO NOT USE for questions about *using* specific compilers or compilation errors." Since this tag obviously does not apply to your question, I have removed it. In future, please make sure that you tag the question correctly.

Comment: Neither C99 nor any other standard version has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some `#if`s

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define __unaligned __attribute__((aligned(1)))
#endif

typedef __unaligned struct __attribute__((packed)){
    int a;
    int b;
}a_b;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu", sizeof(a_b));
}
```

- you need to use the correct printf format too.

EDIT: **IT WORKS SAME AS KEIL EXTENSION**

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define __unaligned __attribute__((aligned(1)))
#endif

typedef __unaligned struct __attribute__((packed)){
    int a;
    int b;
}a_b;


a_b foo(char *ptr, size_t pos)
{
    a_b *abptr = (void *)(ptr + pos);
    return *abptr;
}
```

Cortex-M0 code:

```
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        movs    r4, r0
        adds    r1, r1, r2
        movs    r2, #8
        bl      memcpy
        movs    r0, r4
        pop     {r4, pc}
```

Cortex-M4 code:

```
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        adds    r4, r1, r2
        ldr     r2, [r1, r2]      @ unaligned
        str     r2, [r0]  @ unaligned
        ldr     r2, [r4, #4]      @ unaligned
        str     r2, [r0, #4]      @ unaligned
        pop     {r4, pc}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GjzdM8oPG

Answer (score 1):

Neither `__unaligned` nor `__attribute__((packed))` is standard C. In fact there is no standard way to disable struct packing.

One way to make it portable is to hide all non-standard extensions behind preprocessor macros:

```cpp
    #ifdef __arm__  // "Keil" compiler, nowadays the "ARM" compiler
      typedef __unaligned struct __attribute__((packed))
    #elif defined(__GNUC__)
      typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) __attribute__((aligned(1)))

    /* and so on, add support for whatever compilers you need here */
    #endif
    {
    
        int a;
        int b;
    }a_b;
```

Another option is to use `#pragma`, if supported by the compiler. `#pragma PACK(1)` is a common non-standard extension which does the same thing as `__attribute__((packed))`. It is at least supported by gcc but I don't know about Keil.

The advantage of pragmas is that a compiler which doesn't recognize a certain pragma just skips it - they were meant to be used for the very purpose of hiding non-portable code.

Comment: As for why the SO code color formatting went nuts in this case, I have no idea...

Comment: `__` is reserved for the implementation but this definition is simply ridiculously difficult to read and maintain. 2. Try it in the real code when you have to apply it to tens or hundreds of declarations.

Comment: @0___________ In real code you'd hide all of this in a #define in some header. Or well, in real code you'd probably avoid "force" packing structs in the first place since it is very problematic for numerous reasons.

Comment: 1. You have an existing code you want to compile using GCC. Declarations are in the .h file. How it will help with reriting every definition your way? 2. Packing in embedded code is not "problematic" and very common

Comment: @0___________ Packing on a 32 bit ARM _is_ problematic, because if there was any padding in the struct, the compiler didn't just add it for fun, but because the CPU requires it. There are better, safer and more portable ways to do serialization/deserialization, but that's another topic.